# After placing the footer at the bottom of the page, container property max-width no longer works

Tags: html, css

*Scenario*:

This is the HTML for both cases:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="__next">
      <div class="container">Content</div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**#CASE1**: Here is the code snippet, where I haven't applied my solution to push the footer to the bottom of the page and as You can see: the `container` div takes the exact space of `max-width: 1780px;`.

Check live: [This works](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-monad-o2k3h7?from-embed)

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 1780px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

**#CASE2**: Unfortunately, when I do add my solution to push the footer at the bottom of the page, the `container` property `max-width` has no longer effect.

Check live: [This does not work](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wildflower-zctubf?from-embed)

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#__next {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 1780px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Can somebody enlighten me what's going on here?

Why the `container` `max-width` in the second case does not display properly and looks like its size is just fitting the content, instead of being `1780px`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most people in the industry can read code. Adding to an executable environment is nice and all but it adds multiple steps that are not needed just to view your issues...please post your code.

Comment: @ViaTech Added the code to description. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: There is no flex in your posted code? And can you describe what you mean by “weird behaviour” and “stops working“?

Comment: @Kokodoko the first CSS code snippet has flex, which for some reason breaks my container class and the max-height has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with flex, you should try to use only flex properties, such as `justify-content` and `flex-grow` to decide the size of the flex items.

In this case you also need to make the `__next` div the same height as the screen. Then you can use `space-between` to make the footer stick to the bottom. If you give the footer a base height and set the grow/shrink options to 0 it will stay fixed. Then you can use `flex-grow` on the container to make it fill the remaining space.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#__next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  flex:0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="__next">
  <div class="container">Content</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question once more for additional clarification. Could You please go trough it again?

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working for you?

Comment: I updated your styles, check the commented code: `
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#__next {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1780px;
  /* margin: 0 auto; ~ this*/
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
`

Comment: That `margin:0 auto` doesn't belong in there. You can set `align-items:center` on the `__next` element to center the children. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9376c4m/ You can read more about flex here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sorry, Sir. This is not the solution: `margin: 0 auto;` is acting the same as Your proposal for `align-items: center;` - except that it is also affecting the other children, which I don't want. If You remove the `min-width` property from Your `fiddle`, the problem will remain.